# How to implement Applicative for State[S, A] in scala / cats

Tags: scala

In [this session](https://github.com/SystemFw/scala-italy-2018/blob/master/shared-state.md) SystemFw gives an example of implementing `State[S, A]` wih vanilla scala, When follow the exmple, I run into a trouble in supplying a Applicative definition for the vanilla State type (In order to get the `commands.traverse` work. See code [here](http://systemfw.org/scala-italy-2018/index.html#/3/5)

I tried to make a implicit def to solve the Applicative instance, but didn't figure out how to deal with the 2 type parameter.

How to implement Applicative for this type:

```
 case class State[S, A](modify: S => (A, S)) {

  def runA(initial: S): A = modify(initial)._1

  def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] =
    State { s =>
      val (result, nextState) = modify(s)
      f(result).modify(nextState)
    }
  }
```

Wrong code:

```scala
  implicit def stateApplicative[S, A]: Applicative[State[S, A]] = new Applicative[State[S, A]] {
    override def pure[A](x: A): State[A???] = ???   // error

    override def ap[A, B](ff: State[A => B])(fa: State[A???]): State[B] = ???   // error
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, the solution to this problem is always fixing one type parameter.

In the case of a **State** you want the value inside the state to change but no the type of the state itself so you fix `S`.
So you can create an application for a given particular state, for example `Int`

```scala
type IntState[A] = State[A, Int]

implicit final val intStateApplicative: Applicative[IntState] =
  new Applicative[IntState] {
    // Some implementation.
  }
```

However, after you fill the implementation you will see that the fact of knowing that `S` was `Int` was meaningless. And that we could just copy and paste the whole code if `S` would have been `String` or whatever.
So, what we want is a way to say that this works for any `S`, we can do that with a type lambda *(i.e. a function in the type level)*.

```scala
type StateTypeFun[S] = { type F[A] = State[A, S] }

implicit final def stateApplicative[S]: Applicative[StateTypeFun[S]#F] =
  new Applicative[StateTypeFun[S]#F] {
    // Some implementation.
  }
```

And that is how we solve this problem.
Note that the type alias is unnecessary but makes the code easier to read, but you could have done `Applicative[({ type F[A] = State[A, S]})#F]`.

---

BTW, because this necessity of creating type lambdas is somewhat common in **Scala 2** we have [kind projector](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector), and **Scala 3** has proper [syntax support](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/new-types/type-lambdas-spec.html) for it.